# Why doesn't asp.net core model binding work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my view

```
@model MyProject.ViewModel.CourseViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddCourseView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Add Course</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Course.CourseName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Course.CourseName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Course.CourseName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <label>Select lecturers to the course</label>
            @{
                var lst = Model.List;
                @for (int i = 0; i<lst.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var lecturer = lst.ElementAt(i);
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox @i" asp-for=@lecturer.IsChecked>@lecturer.LecturerId</label>
                    </div>


                }

                @if (lst.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <span class="badge badge-danger" style="font-size:medium">Lecturers list is empty</span>
                    </div>
                }
            }
            <p></p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The view call AddCourse

This is my controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AddCourse()
        {
            var lst = userService.GetAllLecturers();
            CourseViewModel courseViewModel = new CourseViewModel();
            courseViewModel.List = new List<IsCheckedLecturer>();

            foreach(var lecture in lst)
            {
                courseViewModel.List.Add(new IsCheckedLecturer
                {
                    IsChecked = false,
                    LecturerId = lecture.UserId
                });
            }


            return View(courseViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddCourse(CourseViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

HttpGet work fine, but the HttpPost method(the second method) get a null list instead of get the model from the view(by model binding)

This is the courseViewModel

```
    public class CourseViewModel
    {
        public Course Course { get; set; }
        public IList<IsCheckedLecturer> List { get; set; }

    }

    public class IsCheckedLecturer
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string LecturerId { get; set; }
    }
```

why doesn't model binding work? and how i fix it?
Maybe because its complex view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'm assuming you just mean that the `List` property of `viewModel` is null, not `viewModel` itself. The reason for that is that you're not binding the input(s) correctly.

```
var lst = Model.List;
@for (int i = 0; i<lst.Count(); i++)
{
    var lecturer = lst.ElementAt(i);
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox @i" asp-for=@lecturer.IsChecked>@lecturer.LecturerId</label>
    </div>
}
```

The code above will result in the input having a name of `lecturer.IsChecked`. There's nothing to bind this to when it gets back server-side (there's no `lecturer` param), so the model binder just drops it, leaving your `List` property null.

Instead, you need to change your code to something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox@i" asp-for="List[i].IsChecked">@Model.List[i].LecturerId</label>
    </div>
}
```

With that, the name of the input will end up as something like `List[0].IsChecked`, which will then bind to the `List` property on your model.